# GraphX Disk size running low

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am currently using Apache Spark with Graphx, I have noticed lately that when I run my application with a lots of data the application is using a large part of my disk, for example before I start the program the disk is around 8 GB and during the application runs it goes down to 1 GB, when I close the application the disk is restored but not in full. I have lost some GB, at first I though that it had to do with swap memory and logs, but I can not find what is stored to my disk after the execution of the application.

Can someone explain why is this happening?

Comment: How large are the files and how much free RAM do you have when you run the process?

Comment: For RAM 6 GB and file size around 305 KB.

Comment: I don't think the overhead of a 305KB file within a graph should be anywhere near 1GB

Comment: I know it is strange but i cant find out what is happening